# Is a regular stochastic matrix definitely nonsingular?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is a regular stochastic matrix definitely nonsingular (invertible)? How to prove it ?

It says here that 'For a regular matrix always an inverse matrix exists' 
http://www.vias.org/tmdatanaleng/hl_regularmatrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not always. Consider the all-one matrix normalised by its size.

By the way, what you call a *regular matrix* is usually known as a *primitive matrix*.

Comment: If the regular matrix is not a doubly stochastic matrix, does the inverse matrix always exists?

Comment: @Gamp No. It's very easy to construct a counterexample. Take any two entrywise positive probability vectors $u,v\in\mathbb R^3$ (so that the sum of all elements in each vector is equal to 1). Then the augmented $A=(au+bv,\,cu+dv,\,v)\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ is column-stochastic (and $A^T$ is row-stochastic) when $au+bv$ and $cu+dv$ are any two convex combinations of $u$ and $v$, but $A$ is singular because its rank is at most 2.